# Would it be possible to add a search to our comments that we have left for people?

Tags: feature-request

I have written people a lot of comments here and when I look in my profile to find something that I wrote to someone I have to go through pages and pages of comments to find the exact thing I was looking for.  I have 196 pages right now.  :)

Is there a way that we can have a Search added to the Comments under All Actions in our profiles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

+1 to the FR

[Related on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)

Two workarounds in the meantime:

1. Use [an SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/845560/search-for-comments-by-a-user-with-particular-text). This only finds comments posted before the most recent data update (they update the data more or less every Sunday at varying times), but newer comments should be findable in the first few pages of [the comment tab in your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=comments).
2. Ask a mod to search for you. You can ping me any time in [AUGR](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), though sometimes I am asleep or otherwise afk, so this is not very convenient for you, but we have got a per user comment text search box that finds comments too new for SEDE (and even deleted ones).

Comment: I like your options here!  They seem to be easier than that search query on the Stack Exchange.  I can never remember what is needed to get the search to work right without that thing constantly in my face.  :)  Thank you Zanna!